# babel6 how to move _interopRequireDefault to window in browserify

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I use babel6 to transform my es6 code to es5, and bundle it with `browserify`

I find in every file include `_interopRequireDefault` function to include package.
I want remove it from every file, and add it to window can be used in everywhere.

Comment: When the content is gzipped for transmission, the presence of the repeated helper should have essentially no effect on the overall amount of data being transferred. Are you sure this is worth it?

Comment: @loganfsmyth yes, I'm sure. I don't want to use many memory for instance function

Comment: Have you manually tested this? If you manually delete it from the file and add a global, does it actually help? This seems like a case of premature optimization.